# Missing WatchOS Xcode Glance Interface View

Tags: xcode, apple-watch-glances

I am using Xcode 8.2.1. I have an existing project. I choose File -> New -> Target -> Watch OS -> WatchKit App

There are no options to add glances to the project. Nor are glances available in the side menu with various controllers and views.

Have glances been deprecated?  If not, how can I get them available to a project. They also do not show up for new projects.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Glances have been removed in watchOS 3 (https://www.macworld.com/article/3083906/wearables/watchos-3-faq-glances-are-going-away-as-watch-apps-speed-up-and-move-to-a-dock.html)

Instead, apps are now expected to behave nicely in the Dock, which is a replacement of the Glances view. I suggest you watch the WWDC videos ('16 and '17) about what's new in the Apple Watch SDK.